# Word default folder is different when started programmatically

Tags: file, batch-file, ms-word, location, default

We have a 2 step process that collects all filenames from a folder into a Word document for use elsewhere.

The original process was to run an old DOS batchfile that collected the filenames into a DOS .txt.  Then we launched a Word .docx with a macro that imported the .txt and massaged the formatting.  After visual inspection we hit ‘Save’ and that was it.

I had the bright idea that a step could be taken out by launching Word directly from the batch, so I inserted the line:    start winword *filename*.  This works great except that the default location that Word wants to save in is now my Templates folder.   Running it the old way still works perfectly.

The question is: why is the default location changed by launching Word programmatically and how can it be forced back to the correct location?

Thanks

Comment: Read the help file for the START command. I bet you find a helpful option in there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
start /D C:\path\to\folder "" winword.exe
```

this program starts `winword.exe` and save all files to `C:\path\to\folder`
ill assume that `winword.exe` is in the current directory.
for help with the `start` command : http://ss64.com/nt/start.htm

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the start command, but never did figure out why it operated differently.    The eventual solution was to include the Save action in the macro.  I still don't know why we didn't have to do that before, but it works now so we're declaring success and moving on.